# Using FILTER and LEN to turn 100 Columns into 1 Column? Or other method?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter

In Google Sheets I am using the following code to return three columns of data into one column:

`=FILTER({A1:A7;B1:B8;C1:C8}, LEN({A1:A7;B1:B8;C1:C8}))`

This test code works. Now I want to do the same with 100 Columns. Is there a way to do this without having to write out every last range?

Once I have all this data in one column, I would like to display 41 rows of the data in a new sheet in Column A and then continue the data in Column B for the next 41 rows, then Column C, and so on.

The original data looks like so:

```
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | ...
Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | ...
cell1 | cell2 | cell3 | cell4 | ...
etc...
```

So I figure I can pull these into one column and then hopefully distribute this column over multiple columns after every 41 rows. I appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TOCOL to stack all the range in one column. The second parameter lets you choose if you want to skip empty cells (1 if you want), and the third if you want to scan by column or by row. I understand that 1 in this parameter would work for you:

```
=TOCOL(A1:CV20,1,1)
```

I'm using A1:CV20 that is a range as an example, adapt it to yours. Then with WRAPROWS or WRAPCOLS you'll be able to do the 41 rows set. If you do it with WRAPROWS it will take the column and expand it over the columns

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:CV20,1,1),41,)
```

Or you can try with WRAPCOLS and use the number of elements divided by 41:

```
=WRAPCOLS(TOCOL(A1:CV20,1,1),ROUNDUP(COUNTA(TOCOL(A1:CV20,1,1))/41),)
```

Or, with LET so you don't repeat the range:

```
=LET(d,TOCOL(A1:CV20,1,1),
WRAPCOLS(d,ROUNDUP(COUNTA(d,),)
```

I guess that one of those options will do your expected scenario!

Comment: This is great! The one that works best for me is <=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:CV20,1,1),41,)>. Do you know of a way to filter out empty cells so they do not feature?

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! TOCOL(A1:CV20,1,1) --> the first1 leaves empty cells away from your range

Comment: It is showing empty cells, but because this is text data that has been heavily worked on, I know that most empty cells are actually "" cells, or a text thread of zero characters. Sheets thinks this is a value. The FILTER function seems to get rid of the empties. Or maybe you know of another way?

Comment: You can try to use FILTER along with TOCOL: `=WRAPROWS(FILTER(TOCOL(A1:CV20,,1),LEN(TOCOL(A1:CV20,,1))),41,)` - Or, again, with LET: `=LET(d,TOCOL(A1:CV20,,1),WRAPROWS(FILTER(d,LEN(d)),41,))`

Comment: YES! Anonymous user1132149—Martin—you've saved my bacon today. I am super grateful. Many Thanks!

Comment: In the end I used the following: `=WRAPCOLS(FILTER(TOCOL(Sheet1!E2:N350,,0),LEN(TOCOL(Sheet1!E2:N350,,0))),42,)`. My data is a row-based spreadsheet of member data. Your answer allows me to turn my row-based member information into a beautiful directory with three columns on a page (41 rows)! For those who want to do the same, I added an extra column in the member spreadsheet, which was 4 spaces on every row. This shows up as a blank between items in the directory. Using UPPER ahead of time makes the names all caps. A nested substitute function can make the names all bold.